# Firestore - not able to fetch all documents in collections

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing a weird issue when trying to fetch the all documents under the collection.
Below is code to fetch the data from the firestore collection: "UserDetail"

```
db.enableNetwork();
db.collection("UserDetail")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        private static final String TAG = "UserDetail";
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult())
                {
                    String userEmail = document.getData().get("email").toString();
                   
                    if (userEmail != null && !userEmail.equalsIgnoreCase(current_user_email))
                    {
                       <Performing some operation here.>
                    }
                }
                
            } 
        }
    });
```

On new user registration, I am pushing User detail in this collection.
So here is what actually happening: when I register a user User1 on device1, then this code is returning the User1 in the result, but when I am trying to run the code from another device2 then User1 is not being fetched...

Can someone please help me here, not sure what is happening here.

UserDetail collection: this is how the data is getting stored under this collection. In screen shows there are 3 documents under UserDetail collection:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T45Nx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0qMN.png)

Comment: it is possible you are trying to read too fast on device2 before the data is written onto database. or it is possible your code did not actually write to database and your data is still on program memory. can you check your database from firebase console to ensure your data is actually written!?

Comment: Can you also add your database layout to your question?

Comment: No, i am not trying to read fast here. i can see the document added in the UserDetail collection before i try to fetch the User1 detail on device2.
Now...When i login on device2 using the User1 account, after that this code will fetch the User1 detail.
Is this something related to firebase offline cache? But in this code i am using db.enableNetwork to force it read online data only.

@AliasCartellano what do u mean by database layout? Like UserDetail there are several other collections which are storing data. Using firestore's ".setPersistenceEnabled(true)" setting to acceess offline data.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added screenshot of UserDetail collection in Firestore. Hope this is what you are asking for.

Comment: When you say it doesn't return user1, is that at the `String userEmail =...` point, or at the `<Performing some operation here>` point?

Comment: Please provide a more detailed screen, as e don't see the collection.

Comment: @TylerV It dosen't get into "task.getResult()", so the documentsnapshot is not having the User1.

Comment: @AlexMamo  i have added another screenshot. Currently i have changed the collection name to "Users".

Comment: So it's not about `db.collection("UserDetail")` it's about `db.collection("Users")`, right?

Comment: Yes, now i have named the collection to "Users", now but the issue is still there.

Comment: Your code doesn't reach `task.getResult()`?

Comment: @AliasCartellano i mean, its not entering in the far loop as the task.getResult() don't have the result to process.